# Sleep in Hobby Plan App

Tags: heroku

I hope this question belongs here. I have question regarding app in Hobby plan.

Is it possible configure sleep time in Hobby plan app like in current free or eco plan?
So after let say 30 minutes of inactivity app will turn of?

Best, Mateusz

Answer (score 1):

The Free and Hobby plans are being [retired](https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq) November 28th, 2022. The Eco plan replaces these plans, and it behaves similarly; your Eco dynos will sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity. If you want apps that *don't* sleep, you need to upgrade to a higher-level dyno.